# Workflow doesn't send Mail

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

I created a workflow with send mail action. When users add new item to the list, the workflow works. It sends mail to admin.

I created new item but mail doesn't send. When I look

> The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly.

Server administrator checked email settings, it is working. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try to test email settings with creating an alert on list?

Comment: @SlavenSemper alert? I added new item on list

Comment: By setting an alert on a list you can make sure that outgoing mail settings are configured correctly.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues of note to consider when troubleshooting email issues. In both on-premises and SharePoint Online installations, ensure that all addresses on the To: and Cc: lines are valid email addresses. In on-premises installations, ensure that email settings on the server are configured correctly.

Review the following to ensure that you have correctly configured incoming and outgoing emails.

- [Deployment guide for Microsoft SharePoint 2013](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/F/6/1F6D3BE4-1174-4320-A1D1-C0E2681CCCF3/Deployment-guide-for-SharePoint-2013.pdf)
- [How to configure Incoming and Outgoing emails in SharePoint Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pareshg/archive/2010/04/23/how-to-configure-incoming-and-outgoing-emails-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn449112%28v=office.15%29.aspx#bkmk_error07

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error but only on very rare instances. I finally determined that the recipient was one of (2) employees with the exact same name. I then determined that my Email Action seems to be sending to Created By | Display Name. I set it to Created By | Email Address. Now testing.